# Can't create Projection Coordinate System in GeoTiff

Tags: gdal, geotiff

I have a jpg image that I would like to convert to a GeoTiff.  I have done the following with GDAL:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84" -of GTiff -co "INTERLEAVE=PIXEL" -a_ullr -112.749767303467 40.2223700746836 -112.731463909149 40.2063119735618 image0.jpg image0.tif
```

This provides a GeoTiff with the following Geo Data (using gdalinfo):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF    
Files: image0.tif    
Size is 853, 980    
Coordinate System is:    
GEOGCS["WGS 84",     
    DATUM["WGS_1984",    
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,    
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],    
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],    
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],    
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],    
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]    
Origin = (-112.749767303467000,40.222370074683603)    
Pixel Size = (0.000021457672120,-0.000016385817471)    
Metadata:    
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area    
Image Structure Metadata:    
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL    
Corner Coordinates:    
Upper Left  (-112.7497673,  40.2223701) (112d44'59.16"W, 40d13'20.53"N)    
Lower Left  (-112.7497673,  40.2063120) (112d44'59.16"W, 40d12'22.72"N)    
Upper Right (-112.7314639,  40.2223701) (112d43'53.27"W, 40d13'20.53"N)    
Lower Right (-112.7314639,  40.2063120) (112d43'53.27"W, 40d12'22.72"N)    
Center      (-112.7406156,  40.2143410) (112d44'26.22"W, 40d12'51.63"N)    
Band 1 Block=853x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red    
Band 2 Block=853x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green    
Band 3 Block=853x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

I now want to add a projection to the file using gdalwarp so I do this:

```
gdalwarp  -of GTiff -co "INTERLEAVE=PIXEL" -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84" -    t_srs "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84" -r cubic image0.tif image0proj.tif
```

The output from gdal info for this is:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF    
Files: image0proj.tif    
Size is 974, 860    
Coordinate System is:    
GEOGCS["WGS 84",    
    DATUM["WGS_1984",    
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,    
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],    
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],    
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],    
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],    
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]    
Origin = (-115.489754008884220,0.000362780166170)    
Pixel Size = (0.000000000168394,-0.000000000168394)    
Metadata:    
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area    
Image Structure Metadata:    
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL    
Corner Coordinates:    
Upper Left  (-115.4897540,   0.0003628) (115d29'23.11"W,  0d 0' 1.31"N)    
Lower Left  (-115.4897540,   0.0003626) (115d29'23.11"W,  0d 0' 1.31"N)    
Upper Right (-115.4897538,   0.0003628) (115d29'23.11"W,  0d 0' 1.31"N)    
Lower Right (-115.4897538,   0.0003626) (115d29'23.11"W,  0d 0' 1.31"N)    
Center      (-115.4897539,   0.0003627) (115d29'23.11"W,  0d 0' 1.31"N)    
Band 1 Block=974x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red    
Band 2 Block=974x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green    
Band 3 Block=974x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

I was expecting the output to contain projection information in UTM starting like this:
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["UTM",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

JC

Comment: Did you add +proj=utm to t_srs? It looks like you have latlong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  If I use +proj=utm in t_srs I get a project coordinate system and gdalinfo states the following:    Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["UTM Zone 0, Northern Hemisphere",    I tried added the zone also but it still comes out to 0.    Nevermind my bad I forgot to put the + in front of zone=12.  much appreciated I was spinning in circles

Comment: `t_` = target, and `s_` = source, also, if you already have assigned a projection to the source, you can leave out the `s_src` when using `gdalwarp`, it will read the source projection from the inputfile.